# Error encountered attempting to update a categorized view

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

We have Exchange 2010 SP2. We encountered several errors in application event log with event ID 1243:

```
Error encountered attempting to update a categorized view to reflect an operation on a message. 
Database:      DB1   
Folder: ??? 
MsgHeader ID: ***** 
Folder ID: ***** 
Categorization ID: ***** 
Document ID: *****
Message Operation: 0 
Function: EcCategorizeMessage 
Error Code: 0x48a
```

I used exfolder and I found name of affected mailbox and name of folder, which reports error (according FolderID).

[image]

Have you ever met with this event ID 1243? Do you know what is MS-OLK-BGPooledSearchFolder or how to continue in investigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is it. I created some test conditions in my "Search Folders"

[image]

I reloaded the Exfolders and I can see these folders in it.

[image]

Now I know how to create a new folders, but I do not know how to create this one:
MS-OLK-BGPooledSearchFolder_variousnumbers

Comment: I found out that mentioned categorized view is not from Outlook. It has to be Blackberry or some other tool which uses "Search Folders" to receive data from mailbox. We will ask the user and we will see.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try restarting MsExchangeIS ?
I believe these are cached (corrupted ?) database views, which should go away after a msExchangeIS restart.

I havent encountered this error BTW.

Comment: Hi, thanks for information. Unfortunately I cannot restart MsExchangeIS, because there are running a lot of mailboxes (24x7). We will see during next scheduled outage. Anyway thanks for hint.

Comment: 1d59E8 > Is that a BB Pin ?

Comment: Can you check if the user is using Blackberry and find the PIN from their handset. I am not sure if you can find this from IIS logs?
BB doesnt use Exchange ActiveSync, otherwise you would be able to run Get-ActiveSyncDevice and get device ID' using that.